# errno 2 in Python - No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to compute the maximum from each file in my data directory, with the following code:

```
from os import listdir 

def max_files(dir):
    l = listdir(dir)
    for n in l:
        list_num(n)

def list_num(file):
    f = open(file)
    lines = f.readlines()   
    v=[]
    for n in lines:
        for s in n.split():
            v.append(float(s))  
            mx = v[0]  
            maxi=[] 
            for i in v:
                if i > mx:
                    mx = i
                    maxi.append(mx)
            continue
       continue
    return maxi

print max_files(path)
```

I also checked my path, and it's completely correct. The error is:

```
f = open(file)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bvp.txt'
```

`bvp.txt` is the first file listed in the data directory.

Why does this problem occur, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You've run into a common confusion when using the return value of functions that return lists of files in a directory.

`listdir` is just returning the list of files in that directory.  It's not returning the *path* to those files, just the file name.  So unless the directory on which you're operating is the current directory, this won't work; you're trying to open each file in the current directory.

Whenever using the results of `listdir`, if you're not going to change working directories into that directory, you need to add the directory name back to the file before you open it.  Therefore, pass the full path to the file to `list_num` instead of just the file name:

```
list_num(dir + '/' + n)
```